# How to pass tap gesture through point on screen that is not in full-screen UITableView's UIEdgeInsets:

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have created a screen in which I have a full-screen `UITableView`, I set  `UIEdgeInsets` to it, which I have configured as follows:

```
categoriesTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: HEADER_VIEW_HEIGHT, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

where `HEADER_VIEW_HEIGHT` is `CGFloat = 160`.

This allowed me to add a "header view" to the `UITableView` which is getting covered when I start scrolling the `UITableView` (...and not getting stuck above the UITableView, as a real header view will).

**The Problem:** The problem is that I need to have 3 clickable views in the header view, So I designed 3 views in the storyboard and configured `Tap Gesture Recognizers` on them. But when I try to use them the tap gestures are not passed throw the `UITableView` even though I see those views on screen (as a result of the contentInset configuration). The only way I can make them tapable/clickable is if I set `User Interaction Enabled` to false on the `UITableView` (which I can't do because I need the `UITableView` to be draggable and clickable as well).

**The Question:** How would I pass the tap events to the lower "header view" clickable parts when it's not covered by the `UITableView` as a result of the contentInset setting?

Here is the UI image, in it you can see that there is a full-screen `UITableView`, behind it there a view with 3 subviews that contains 3 favorite items which I can present to the user for an easier access. when the screen starts, there is a contentInset for the `UITableView` hence the user can see those easy access options and press them (which he can't do right now). When the user starts scrolling, the `UITableView` goes on top of the layout with the 3 views and the user able to scroll the list in a full screen. kind of like a parallax effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**I have a very ugly solution for this..**

Now you have a table view and below that there is a header view right? Add one more view on top of table view which contains 3 sub views in it and all transparent in colour.

Position this newly added subview same as that of header view (Either by programmatically giving same frame as that of header view or by connecting its top, left, bottom and right constraints to the header view). Similarly position the 3 sub views of this new view as same as that of the subviews inside the header view. And give tap gesture to the subviews of this new view. So our user will think he is tapping the header view, whereas he is actually tapping in this invisible view.

And if you want to get touch in the table view once it scrolls up and cover the header view, then you can use one of these two..

1. Call the UIScrollViewDelegate delegate method scrollViewDidScroll() and inside if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 160, set the User Interaction Enabled to false for this newly added view and revert that back to true if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 160.
2. Or from inside scrollViewDidScroll(), assign `outletOfTopConstraintOfYourNewView.constant = -(scrollView.contentOffset.y)`, so that the new view will also move up according to the scroll, thereby changing its visible tappable area.

**Another not so elegant idea is..**

Instead of giving contentInset, add one more section in this table view at the 0th index with only one cell whose height is 160, user interaction enabled is false and colour is transparent. Then you don't  have to worry about the logic in scrollViewDidScroll().

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something like that, but like you said this is indeed an ugly solution and I was hoping for something more elegant that I can use in the system to pass the tap to existing view rather than creating a new transparent one. If I will have no other suggestions I will probably go for that, out of no other options, but I'm hoping this is not the case. giving you +1 for now, for the desire to help

Comment: I have made an edit to the answer. Please check that also.

Comment: I can't really use your second suggestion in my case as I have a shadow on the UITableView by design. So if I add a first transparent view the shadow will fall after it which will result in a bad look. In any other case, I think this would be the better solution, well maybe except the fact that you will need to handle the data with a +1 shift.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Below solution is not perfect but it may give you a direction to start with.

A) Put the top constraint of tableView top to bottom constraint of headerview.

B) Create IBOutlet of height constraint of headerview in your ViewController

C) Listen to tableview's ScrollViewDidScroll and put code like this

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            if y > 50{
                if heightConstant.constant != 0{
                    view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    heightConstant.constant = 0
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }, completion: nil)

                }
            }else{
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
                heightConstant.constant = 160
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

### Here 50 is a point form where it should start animating. It is somewhat similar to Collapsable Toolbar in Android. Just make sure headerView.isClipsToBounds = true.

---

Convert your headerview into a UITableViewCell and in change your UITableViewDataSource as

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return section == 0 ? 1 : yourList.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            // set your header view here
        }else{
            // Your normal cell configuration
        }
    }
}
```

With this, your headerview will become a part of table view but as a UITableViewCell thus it will not behave like sticky header like the normal one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't really use your suggestion in my case as I have a shadow on the UITableView by design. So if I add a view as the first section then the shadow will fall after it which will result in a bad look.

Comment: @EmilAdz Can you post an Image of UI.

Comment: His desired effect is different @SahilManchanda. He actually wants the sticky behaviour. But rather than table view going behind the header view while scrolling, he wants the table view to slide through the top of header view, thereby hiding it (Kind of like the scroll in contact info page of whatsapp).

Comment: @SahilManchanda, posted in the question, thanks for your help.

Comment: @SahilManchanda, I tried your second suggestion right now, sorry that it took me some time, got other assignments. The problem is that this feels laggy because of the animation that is reacting to the tableview scroll, I managed to get a much better and on point response with my previous implementation when I really on the tableview scroll for changing bounds and constraints instead of firing another animation.